# When to use "in" and "at"

Tags: differences

when do I use "in" and "at" in a sentence? for example is "I will coming to learn English in India or At India"

Comment: You've asked a surprisingly complex question, since English prepositions are not especially regular. See for example [this table listing specific use cases for prepositions](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/prepositions) and [this George Carlin routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMTadkoWG9k).

Comment: Ah! Good link @Dan

Comment: When I was a child taking piano exams, I remember noticing that the information about composers printed in the exam books made a distinction between large and smaller cities, e.g. "W.A. Mozart, born at Salzburg 1756, died in Vienna 1791." I wouldn't make that distinction myself, though I might say "at [a small village]" rather than "in".

Answer (score 1):

When defining places "in" generally refers to a city, state country etc., whereas "at" usually refers to specific locatons within them, e.g., in India, but at the station.

Answer (score 0):

We should use at for very Specific conditions.
Example: 
we will move at 12:45pm

On - not that much specific 
We can use for a day or for a date.
Example:
We shall meet on holiday.
We shall go on Monday.

In covers wider place or time etc
Example:
I was born in November
I was born in India
I was born in 1991